# Notify or update data in browser with asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have asterisk on a server 104.x.x.x and a main website on another server(204.x.x.x). Now I want to update the browser when someone call a sip number from my asterisk. Is there a better way of doing it? What I'm thinking is to expose an api that will update my telephony system database and do a ajax pooling or websocket on the browser from my website and call that api from dialplan via AGI method, but not sure if that is possible. Vicidial and other telephony system software works this way because their web application was also installed on the same server as asterisk. What this softwares do is call an external php or other language script from their dialplan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Asterisk manager API:
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Monitor
to monitor calls from remote server.
Please check the manager.conf file, on how to allow access to a remote IP,
here's an example:

```
[usernamehere]
secret=yourpasswordhere
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=204.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
read=all,system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,originate
;write=command,call,originate
displayconnects=yes
```

You only need the "write" part if you intend to interact from the remote location back, like hanging up a call...